# How to write csv file from scraped data from web in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape data from web pages and able to scrape also.
After using below script getting all div class data but I am confused how to write data in CSV file like.

First Data in the first name column 
Last name data in last name column
.
.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = 'http://rerait.telangana.gov.in/PrintPreview/PrintPreview/UHJvamVjdElEPTQmRGl2aXNpb249MSZVc2VySUQ9MjAyODcmUm9sZUlEPTEmQXBwSUQ9NSZBY3Rpb249U0VBUkNIJkNoYXJhY3RlckQ9MjImRXh0QXBwSUQ9'

page = urlopen(html)

data = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

name_box = data.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 'col-md-3 col-sm-3'}) #edited companyName_99a4824b -> companyName__99a4824b

for i in range(len(name_box)):
    data = name_box[i].text.strip()
```

Data:

```
Information Type
Individual

First Name
KACHAM
Middle Name

Last Name
RAJESHWAR
Father Full Name
RAMAIAH
Do you have any Past Experience ?
No
Do you have any registration in other State than registred State?
No
House Number
8-2-293/82/A/446/1
Building Name
SAI KRUPA
Street  Name
ROAD NO 20
Locality
JUBILEE HILLS
Landmark
JUBILEE HILLS
State
Telangana
Division
Division 1
District
Hyderabad
Mandal
Shaikpet
Village/City/Town

Pin Code
500033
Office Number
04040151614
Fax Number

Website URL

Authority Name

Plan Approval Number
1/18B/06558/2018
Project Name
SKV S ANANDA VILAS
Project Status
New Project
Proposed Date of Completion
17/04/2024
Litigations related to the project ?
No
Project Type
Residential
Are there any Promoter(Land Owner/ Investor) (as defined by Telangana RERA Order) in the project ?
Yes
Sy.No/TS No.
00
Plot No./House No.
10-2-327
Total Area(In sqmts)
526.74
Area affected in Road widening/FTL of Tanks/Nala Widening(In sqmts)
58.51
Net Area(In sqmts)
1
Total Building Units (as per approved plan)
1
Proposed Building Units(as per agreement)
1


Boundaries East
PLOT NO 213
Boundaries West
PLOT NO 215
Boundaries North
PLOT NO 199
Boundaries South
ROAD NO 8
Approved Built up Area (In Sqmts)
1313.55
Mortgage Area  (In Sqmts)
144.28
State
Telangana
District
Hyderabad
Mandal
Maredpally
Village/City/Town

Street
ROAD NO 8
Locality
SECUNDERABAD COURT
Pin Code
500026
```

above is the data getting after run above code.

**Edit**

```
for i in range(len(name_box)):
    data = name_box[i].text.strip()
    print (data)
    fname = 'out.csv'
    with open(fname) as f:
        next(f)
        for line in f:
            head = []
            value = []
            for row in line:
                head.append(row)
            print (row)
```

**Expected**

```
Information Type | First  | Middle Name | Last Name | ......
Individual       | KACHAM |             | RAJESHWAR | .....
```

I have 200 url but all url data is not same means some of these missing. I want to write such way if data not avaialble then write anotthing just blank.

Please suggest. Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you considered using Pandas? Using the built in functions for scraping web content `pd.read_html()` and writing CSV files `df.to_csv()` may make your code more readable.

Comment: `open(fname)` is only *reading a file*, not writing to it

Comment: yes, it's not writing because, before writing I want to make data such way like expected result. please help

Comment: @Mark, No, How will do in pandas? how to write row data in column name like expected result

Comment: From the pandas module: `pandas.read_html()` will parse the HTML tables into a DataFrame. `df.to_csv()` will convert the DataFrame into CSV. The pandas module documentation is excellent, available at https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_html.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to write to csv you need to know what value should be in head and body, in this case head value should be html element contain `<label`

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = 'http://rerait.telangana.gov.in/PrintPreview/PrintPreview/UHJvamVjdElEPTQmRGl2aXNpb249MSZVc2VySUQ9MjAyODcmUm9sZUlEPTEmQXBwSUQ9NSZBY3Rpb249U0VBUkNIJkNoYXJhY3RlckQ9MjImRXh0QXBwSUQ9'

page = urlopen(html)

data = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

name_box = data.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 'col-md-3 col-sm-3'}) #edited companyName_99a4824b -> companyName__99a4824b

heads = []
values = []

for i in range(len(name_box)):
    data = name_box[i].text.strip()
    dataHTML = str(name_box[i])
    if 'PInfoType' in dataHTML:
        # <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3" id="PInfoType">
        # empty value, maybe additional data for "Information Type"
        continue

    if 'for="2"' in dataHTML:
        # <label for="2">No</label>
        # it should be head but actually value
        values.append(data)

    elif '<label' in dataHTML:
        # <label for="PersonalInfoModel_InfoTypeValue">Information Type</label>
        # head or top row
        heads.append(data)

    else:
        # <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">Individual</div>
        # value for second row
        values.append(data)

csvData = ', '.join(heads) + '\n' + ', '.join(values)    
with open("results.csv", 'w') as f:
    f.write(csvData)

print "finish."
```

Comment: Thank you, Can you please explain these lines: `if 'PInfoType' in dataHTML:
        continue

    if 'for="2"' in dataHTML:
        values.append(data)
    elif '<label' in dataHTML:
        heads.append(data)`

Comment: I am trying for multiple urls but not getting all column in as same in the first link.  second link: `http://rerait.telangana.gov.in/PrintPreview/PrintPreview/UHJvamVjdElEPTE1NiZEaXZpc2lvbj0xJlVzZXJJRD0yMTA2NCZSb2xlSUQ9MSZBcHBJRD0yNDcmQWN0aW9uPVNFQVJDSCZDaGFyYWN0ZXJEPTQ3JkV4dEFwcElEPQ%3d%3d`

Comment: code updated with explanation. for second link just add needed condition `if... elif...`

Comment: Thanks, How to loop for `http://rerait.telangana.gov.in/PrintPreview/PrintPreview/UHJvamVjdElEPTE1NiZEaXZpc2lvbj0xJlVzZXJJRD0yMTA2NCZSb2xlSUQ9MSZBcHBJRD0yNDcmQWN0aW9uPVNFQVJDSCZDaGFyYWN0ZXJEPTQ3JkV4dEFwcElEPQ%3d%3d` this link? and `Plot No. 46 & 47, 2-2-647/8 & 2-2-647/8/2` this value i am getting in two columns buy want in one

Comment: Also suggest for table data in the same link. Can we scrape in the same csv? using same code

Comment: Can you please suggest ? How to loop for http://rerait.telangana.gov.in/PrintPreview/PrintPreview/UHJvamVjdElEPTE1NiZEaXZpc2lvbj0xJlVzZXJJRD0yMTA2NCZSb2xlSUQ9MSZBcHBJRD0yNDcmQWN0aW9uPVNFQVJDSCZDaGFyYWN0ZXJEPTQ3JkV4dEFwcElEPQ%3d%3d this link? and Plot No. 46 & 47, 2-2-647/8 & 2-2-647/8/2 this value i am getting in two columns buy want in one.

Answer (score 0):

> **Question**: How to write csv file from scraped data

Read the `Data` into a `dict` and use `csv.DictWriter(...` to write to CSV file.
Documentations about: 
[csv.DictWriter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) 
[while](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#while) 
[next](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) 
[break](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#break)
[Mapping Types — dict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#index-54)

1. Skip the first line, as it's the title
2. Loop `Data` lines

   1. `key =  next(data)`
   2. `value = next(data)`
   3. Break loop if no further data
   4. Build `dict[key] = value`
3. After finishing the loop, write `dict` to CSV file

> **Output**:
>
> ```
> {'Individual': '', 'Father Full Name': 'RAMAIAH', 'First Name': 'KACHAM', 'Middle Name': '', 'Last Name': 'RAJESHWAR',... (omitted for brevity)
> ```

Comment: I have tried but not getting expected result. Can you please share the code?

Comment: @user10468005: Edit your Question and show your effords, explain where you get stuck.